# hashtable data ordering

Tags: java, hashtable

I am trying to implement a `HashTable` by

```
HashTable ht=new HashTable();
```

In which I am putting value into it by one xml file.

The problem is that when I am printing the value of hashtable its not coming in the same order, Its taking ascending order.

Suppose:- If the keys are [US, AU, CA] with there respective values,then I am trying to get them in same order as they appear in the file(xml), but its coming like [AU, CA, US] with there respective values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Arshad.

Answer (score 8):

> The problem is that when i am printing the value of hashtable its not coming in the same order, Its taking ascending order.

Not necessarily - it will be in some *unspecified* order. You must *not* rely on the order of `Hashtable`.

If you want a map which retains insertion order, use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). (You almost certainly didn't want `Hashtable` in the first place, but `HashMap`.)

To add from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) about ordering of elements in a `HashMap`:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 0):

thats right the hashtable doesn't mind the order you added your values.

Maybe you shoud use a LinkedHashMap or LinkedList.

Answer (score -2):

The key of `HashTable` is sorted according to the natural order for the key's class. Reference `Comparable`.

The keys need to implement `Comparable`, so since your keys are Strings, they do that. The behavior for the keys ordering will be controlled that way only.

Comment: -1: as far as I know the keys of HashTable are not sorted in any way.